# Droid2 Fastboot

Tags: fastboot, motorola-droid-2

How to get the droid 2 to enter fastboot?

Running rooted phone, CM7 nightly 239

Power + x gets me recovery
Power + Up gets me bootloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Droid 2 doesn't have fastboot mode; Its bootloader is locked. Fastboot mode is really just the bootloader mode in other phones, like Nexus phones. Out of curiosity, where exactly did you hear that the D2 had a fastboot mode, and why do you want to access it?

Comment: Ah okay. I remember there being a white screen with the android guys which seems to be described as fastboot. It may have been on one of the other phones that I had rooted though. I'm just checking through my possible recovery options before I flash a new rom (last time I had to SBF the phone, root, and reinstall CWM so i just want to make sure everythings still working ok before I mess it up :) )

Comment: Okay, cool! Glad I was able to help.